# A file share resource on a Windows Cluster loses permissions during a failover

Tags: windows, cluster, network-share

During a failover event on a clustered Windows server, one or more network share resources lose their permissions. Aside from the failover events, no other relevant data is written to the event log.

What is causing the network shares to lose their permissions?

What can be done to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a result of using the Computer Management console (`compmgmt.msc`) to set the share permissions instead of using the Failover Cluster Manager console (`cluadmin.msc`).

Although the Computer Management console can edit the permissions of active shares, the changes are not written to the Cluster's configuration. Therefore, when a failover occurs, the network share resource is recreated using settings read from the Cluster's configuration and any changes made using the Computer Management console are lost.